Additional verification logic when refreshing an access token
I am working on implementing access and refresh tokens with OAuth 2.0. I have implemented a custom grant type, and I can renew the access token using a refresh token with already existing OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationConverter and OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider. The problem is that, before granting a new access token, I need to call the database to verify that the user is still active and perform additional checks (e.g., to determine if they have lost their login eligibility in the meantime). Ideally, I need a call to authenticationManager.authenticate before granting a new access token.
I've tried to implement a OncePerRequest filter for additional validation, but inside it I have no access to the user's username, only to the refresh token, grant type, and scope.
Is there a filter which accepts OAuth2AuthenticationToken and runs just before OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider does?
I also considered copying the entire OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationConverter and adjusting it accordingly. However, I would like to avoid creating a copy of the converter due to maintainability concerns.
Thanks in advance!

Write a custom AuthenticationProvider to perform additional checks.  It will run before OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider runs.  For example:
/**
 * If the user account is locked, then throws an exception, which stops subsequent
 * {@link AuthenticationProvider#authenticate AuthenticationProvider}s being tried.
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsRefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    var authenticationToken = (OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String refreshToken = authenticationToken.getRefreshToken();
    if (userDetailsService.isAccountLocked(refreshToken)) {
      throw new LockedException("User account is locked");
    }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
  }
}

Add this custom AuthenticationProvider into the token endpoint:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(
    HttpSecurity http,
    UserDetailsRefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider userDetailsRefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider
) throws Exception {
  OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

  http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
      .tokenEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint              
          .authenticationProvider(userDetailsRefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider)

  // ...


Thanks for your answer! I saw in the implementation that ".authenticationProvider()" puts specified authentication provider as the first element in the list of authentication providers, and this would work.
In the meantime I implemented a RefreshTokenValidationFilter which extends OncePerRequestFilter and implemented my logic there. In your opinion, which is the better approach, to use a filter or an authentication provider?

Is your RefreshTokenValidationFilter also responsible for reading the parameters from the HTTP request and writing the HTTP response?  Spring Authorization Server's OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter takes care of that, so you only have to implement a custom authentication provider.

It doesn't write response, but if requestURI is oauth/token and it contains refresh_token grant type, it calls the authentication manager with PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken and if everything is fine, then it calls the next filter in the chain with 'filterChain.doFilter(request, response)', otherwise throws an error. Is that a correct way to do it?

Actually, I directly use 'PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate' instead of AuthenticationManager.

If a token request failed, then the OAuth 2.0 specification requires the authorization server to return an error response.  If your filter throws an exception, then what sends the error response?

I am sorry for the delay, somehow I missed your answer. RefreshTokenValidationFilter is added before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, and when it throws an exception, the exception is handled and written into response by the 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)' method. In the response, this method shows only error code, and hides the error description.

By the way, if I implement RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider, do I always have to throw one of the 'AccountStatusException' types in order to prevent the default AuthenticationProvider from refreshing an access token, or is there another way?
When I throw an OAuth2AuthException, an access token is still refreshed by the default RefreshTokenAuhenticationProvider if refresh token is valid.

The Javadoc says you must throw an AccountStatusException to prevent the execution of subsequent providers in the list.

Thank you so much Chin for all the answers. I have implemented it as you proposed.
